# Send Params in data by Ajax in Checkout in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm adding a form with address to connect to my checkout form, I have a collection of radio buttons that give me the possibility to send one answer and store the data in my model and checkout, but when I'm pressing anyone, I saw the parameters in my checkout and are `nil` and debugging in web-console told me that my post petition is not working as you can see in the first image.

[image: JavaScript console]

[image: events/:id/checkout/new view]

I get the following error:

> ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Events::Checkouts::AddressingsController)

I am currently doing the following:

- First I create all the relations, I have two models EventCheckout and Addressing with a polymorphic relation because I need addressing in Order too.
- Second  I did a controller with POO inside Checkouts controller with a create action whose responsibility is responds to JSON success or error, when I create an Addressing, after it create a route with a POST action inside the routes.
- Third create a form who receives inside a radio button an action from JavaScript
- Fourth create a JavaScript with a remote action in AJAX to pass the parameters and see the URL.

```
class Addressing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :address
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true


  def self.for_addressable(addressable, address)
    addressable.address = address
    true
  rescue StandardError => error
    addressable.errors.add(:base, error.message)
    false
  end
end

class EventCheckout < Application Record
  has_one :addressing, as: :addressable
  has_one :address, through: :addressing

  # ...
end
```

```
module Events
  module Checkouts
    class AddressingController < Events::ApplicationController
      before_action :set_checkout, except: :new

      def create
        respond_to do |format|
          format.json do
            if Addressing.for_addressable(@checkout, @address){
              render json: {status: 'success', checkout: @checkout.to_json}
              }
            else
              render json: {status: 'error',
                            message: @checkout.errors.full_messages.to_sentence},
                     status: :unprocessable_entity
            end
          end
        end
      end

      private

      def set_address
        @address = Address.find(addressing_params[:address_id])
      end

      def addressing_params
        params.require(:adressing).permit(:address_id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
resource :addressing, only: :create, module: :checkouts
```

```
<div class="radio_buttons">
<%= bootstrap_form_with(model: address, url: event_checkout_path(event),  data: { url: event_checkout_addressing_path(event) }, method: :patch, local: true, html: {novalidate: true, class: 'needs-validation js-address-method-select'}) do |f| %>
  <% address.map do |address| %>
    <div class="rounded border p-2 hover:cursor-pointer flex items-center mb-2 text-blue-darker">
      <%= f.radio_button_without_bootstrap :address, address.id, class:'mr-4 form-radio js-address-method-option' %>
      <%= address_checkout_icon(address.address_type) %>
      <%= f.label address.address, class:'text-base font-medium mr-4 cursor-pointer' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

JavaScript with action

```
import $ from 'jquery'

export default class AddressMethodSelect {
  constructor() {
    this.attachEvents()
    $('.js-address-method-option').prop('disabled', false)
  }

  attachEvents() {
    $(document).on('change', '.js-address-method-option', event =>
      this.handleChange(event)
    )
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    let url = $('.js-address-method-select').data('url')
    let val = $(event.target).val()
    console.log(url)
    console.log(val)

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        authenticity_token: $('[name="csrf-token"]')[0].content,
        addressing: {
          address_id: val
        }
      },
      success: data => {

      },
      error: data => {

      }
    })
  }
}

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  new AddressMethodSelect()
})
```

- When I press an option of radiobutton im getting the data about the ID of address that im passing in the controller, and the URl when I debug in console of the browser. but my petition has an error SENDING post params in ajax
- Second I dont know how to do a validation that, when I press the radio button generate the JSON response :success and can generate and alert in HTML.

Comment: Can you please post the full `config/routes.rb` and the full path of AddressingController ?

Comment: thanks @DimitriusLachi, well it was an error because it must AddressingsController, but now is detecting my param but is not working well, i have this error No template found for Events::Checkouts::AddressingsController#create, rendering head :no_content